# Series rapresentation $f(t)=\frac{1}{(2t+1)^{2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

How to find the series rapresentation in $t=0$ of the following expression

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{(2t+1)^{2}}$$

Can someone show me also the steps.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Where should the series be centered?

Comment: Are  you asking for a Maclaurin series?

Comment: What about the generalized binomial theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n\enspace$ for $\enspace-1<x<1$ , proof by multiplication with $1-x$ .

One derivation for $x$ gives $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ .

With $x:=-2t$ and therefore $\enspace -\frac{1}{2}< t< \frac{1}{2}$ follows:

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1+2t)^2}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n(-2t)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing f(t) as power instead of as quotient it is easier to calculate the successive derivatives:
$$f(t) = (2t+1)^{-2}$$
$$f'(t) = (-2)(2t+1)^{-3}2$$
$$f''(t) = (-3)(-2)(2t+1)^{-3}2^2$$
$$f^{3}(t) = (-4)(-3)(-2)(2t+1)^{-3}2^3$$
$$\cdots$$
$$f^{n}(t) = \cdots$$
Can you continue?